# Going from custom component item view to edit user view problem

Tags: joomla-3.x, user, custom-component

I've created a custom component that collects user inputted data, and redisplays it in the back end, similar to a contact form. I'm currently trying to set it up so that in both the list and item views, there is a direct link to the `Edit User` page should a `user_id` by associated.

Going from my list page doesn't have any problems, but when going from inside an item, I get the error message: `You are not permitted to use that link to directly access that page (#user_id).`

The link being used to direct to the `Edit User` page is `index.php?option=com_users&view=user&layout=edit&id=*user_id*`

Is there something inherently wrong that I'm doing?

Comment: are you using JRoute for the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this link:

```
index.php?option=com_users&task=user.edit&id=*user_id*
```

Comment: Can you add a bit of explanation to this answer please?